# How does jQuery 2.x uniquely identify an element (in .data())

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In `jQuery 1.x` elements would receive a unique identifier (a cache key) when required, stored in the `ele[jQuery.expando]` property of a node, [set by this line of code](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/04-data.html#section-9). [Mootools uses similar logic](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Slick/Slick.Finder.js#L467-481).

So in `jQuery 1.x`

```
var test = document.createElement("span");
console.log(test[jQuery.expando]);//undefined
$(test).data("test", {stuff:2});
console.log(test[jQuery.expando]);//some uid
```

I was curious, as I'm in the process of implementing similar logic, how jQuery identify a node in `2.x`. Referencing a line number in the github repo would be excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 2 still uses this method, the property is simply harder to detect because it uses a hidden random number as part of the property name, not just the `jQuery.expando`

Its lines 42 and 43 that add the unique data property to the element, the Data.js file is in effect a (mostly) stand-alone class definition that jQuery uses to handle the data storage functionality. I admit that the code is rather convoluted in the repo, but using that as a way of learning how jQuery works is not really recommended, use the commented source at [code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js) to do that instead, it makes understanding how everything interacts much easier.

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/6318ae6ab90d4b450dfadf32ab95fe52ed6331cb/src/data/Data.js#L32-51

Comment: Can you give me an example of either the property name or where they define it?

Comment: It is defined in `data/Data.js` in the repo, and if you check the javascript representation of a dom node with jquery data, it will have a property that looks something like `jquery1426525252650.115245662563` (the constructor being `jQuery.expando+Math.random()`

Comment: I'm sorry, not seeing where they define the uid on elements in https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data/Data.js can you link the line please

Comment: Its lines 42 and 43 that add the unique data property to the element, the Data.js file is in effect a (mostly) stand-alone class definition that jQuery uses to handle the data storage functionality. I admit that the code is rather convoluted in the repo, but using that as a way of learning how jQuery works is not really recommended, use the compiled version at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js to do that instead, it makes understanding how everything interacts much easier.